# Error message when trying to install Cryptodome using setup.py

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, setup.py, pycryptodome

I am setting up python's cryptodome on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. I am using the setup.py module to achieve this. The reason I am using setup.py instead of pip is because the machine that I am installing this on does not have external internet access and thus pip will not work.

I have installed the 64 bit c++ compilers using Windows SDK and have run the following commands on the cmd line per the instructions spelled out from the following [link](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html#windows-from-sources-python-3-3-and-3-4).

- List item cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1"
- List item cmd /V:ON /K Bin\SetEnv.Cmd /x64 /release
- List item set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

When I run setup.py I get the following error message:

```
  File "setup.py", line 443, in <module>
    set_compiler_options(package_root, ext_modules)
  File "C:\Python33\cryptodome\pycryptodome-3.8.2\compiler_opt.py", line 304, in
 set_compiler_options
    clang = compiler_is_clang()
  File "C:\Python33\cryptodome\pycryptodome-3.8.2\compiler_opt.py", line 239, in
 compiler_is_clang
    return test_compilation(source, msg="clang")
  File "C:\Python33\cryptodome\pycryptodome-3.8.2\compiler_opt.py", line 82, in
test_compilation
    objects = compiler.compile([fname], extra_postargs=extra_cc_options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 461, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 372, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 288, in query_vcvarsal
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']
```

Here is the code that looks to be associated with the error:

```
    #looks to contain a set of possible environment variable names
    interesting = set(("include", "lib", "libpath", "path"))


    #populates result with keys and values from actual environment variables
    stdout = stdout.decode("mbcs")
            for line in stdout.split("\n"):
                line = Reg.convert_mbcs(line)
                if '=' not in line:
                    continue
                line = line.strip()
                key, value = line.split('=', 1)
                key = key.lower()
                if key in interesting:
                    if value.endswith(os.pathsep):
                        value = value[:-1]
                    result[key] = removeDuplicates(value)


    #tests whether all the keys within result are in interesting
    if len(result) != len(interesting):
         raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
```

Could this be due to some missing values within the environment variables? If so, what should those vales be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error message isn't very helpful, I fixed this by adding the 3 values: lib, include, libpath (path was already added) to the environment variables on the machine.